# What is the event called down arrow button in Android?

Tags: android, cordova

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnclS.png)

In android when we click on som input box , keyboard popups and backbutton changes to downarrow button. Anyone knows how to get the event of this button.
For backbutton I am getting the event using the below code.
document.addEventListener("buttondown", this.onBackKeyDown, false);

How can I get the event of the other button and can anyone please tell me what is the name of the button?

Answer (score -1):

> Anyone knows how to get the event of this button

There is no event for that button.

> what is the name of the button?

It is the BACK button. It is handled purely by the system when the input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard) is visible.